# Advice on writing a solver for Vexed levels

Tags: python, c, artificial-intelligence, solver, game-ai

Vexed is a popular puzzle game, with many versions available (some of them GPL free software).  It is very suitable for small screen devices; versions are available for Android, iOS, etc.  I discovered it on the PalmOS platform.

Just for fun, I'd like to write a solver that will solve Vexed levels.

Vexed is a block-sliding puzzle game.  Here are the rules in a nutshell:

0) Each level is a grid of squares, bounded by an impassible border.  In any level there will be some solid squares, which are impassible.  There are some number of blocks of various colors; these could be resting on the bottom border, resting on solid squares, or resting on other blocks (of a different color).  Most levels are 8x8 or smaller.

1) The only action you can take is to slide a block to the left or to the right.  Each square traveled by a block counts as one move.

2) There is gravity.  If, after you slide a block, it is no longer resting on a solid square or another block, it will fall until it comes to rest on another block, a solid square, or the bottom border.  Note that you cannot ever lift it up again.

3) Any time two or more blocks of the same color touch, they disappear.  Note that chains are possible: if a supporting block disappears, blocks that rested upon it will fall, which could lead to more blocks of the same color touching and thus disappearing.

4) The goal is to make all blocks disappear in the minimum number of moves.  Each level has a "par score" which tells you the minimum number of moves.  (In the original PalmOS game, the "par score" wasn't necessarily the minimum, but in the Android version I play these days it is the minimum.)

Here is the SourceForge project with the source for the PalmOS version of the game:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/vexed/

I'm an experienced software developer, but I haven't done really any work in AI sort of stuff (pathfinding, problem-solving, etc.)  So I'm looking for advice to get me pointed in the right direction.

At the moment, I can see two basic strategies for me to pursue:

0) Just write a brute-force solver, probably in C for the speed, that cranks through every possible solution for every game and returns a list of all solutions, best one first.  Would this be a reasonable approach, or would the total number of possible moves make this too slow?  I don't think any levels exist larger than 10x10.

1) Learn some AI-ish algorithms, and apply them in a clever way to solve the problem, probably using Python.

Note that the source for PalmOS Vexed includes a solver.  According to the author, "The solver uses A* with pruning heuristics to find solutions."

http://www.scottlu.com/Content/Vexed.html

So, one strategy I could pursue would be to study the A* algorithm and then study the C++ code for the existing solver and try to learn from that.

I'm going to tag this with Python and C tags, but if you think I should be using something else, make your sales pitch and I'll consider it!

Here is ASCII art of a level from "Variety 25 Pack"; level 48, "Dark Lord".  I am able to solve most levels but this one has, well, vexed me.  Par score for this level is 25 moves, but I have not yet solved it at all!

```
__________
|## g####|
|## # b##|
|## # p##|
|#g   ###|
|bp   ###|
|p# p g  |
==========
```

In this picture, the borders are underscores, vertical bars, and equals characters.  Filled-in squares are '#'.  Open spaces are space characters.  Colored blocks are 'g' (green), 'b' (blue) and 'p' (purple).

By the way, I'll likely make the input file format to the solver be ASCII art of the levels, just like this but without the fussy line border characters.

Thanks for any advice!

EDIT:

I have accepted an answer.  Thank you to the people who gave me answers.

This is a semi-brute-force solver.  It isn't using A* but it is cutting short unprofitable branches of the tree.

It reads in a simple text file with the level data.  A letter is a block, a '_' (underscore) is an open space, and a '#' is a filled-in space.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Solve levels from the game Vexed.


from collections import Counter
import sys


level_blocks = set(chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1))
level_other = set(['_', '#'])
level_valid = set().union(level_blocks, level_other)


def prn_err(s='\n'):
    sys.stderr.write(s)
    sys.stderr.flush()


def validate_llc(llc):
    if len(llc) == 0:
        raise ValueError, "need at least one row of level data"
    w = len(llc[0])
    if w < 2:
        raise ValueError, "level data not wide enough"
    for i, row in enumerate(llc):
        if len(row) != w:
            s = "level data: row %d is different length than row 0"
            raise ValueError, s % i
        for j, ch in enumerate(row):
            if ch not in level_valid:
                s = "char '%c' at (%d, %d) is invalid" % (ch, i, j)
                raise ValueError, s


class Info(object):
    pass

info = Info()

info.width = 0
info.height = 0
info.spaces = set()
info.boom_blocks = set()
info.best_solution = 9999999999
info.title = "unknown"



class Level(object):
    """
    Hold the state of a level at a particular move.  self.parent points
    to the previous state, from a previous move, so the solver builds a
    tree representing the moves being considered.  When you reach a solution
    (a state where there are no more blocks) you can walk up the tree
    back to the root, and you have the chain of moves that leads to that
    solution."""
    def __init__(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, Level):
            self.blocks = dict(x.blocks)
            self.colors = dict(x.colors)
            self.parent = x
            self.s_move = ''
            self.rank = x.rank + 1
        else:
            if isinstance(x, basestring):
                # allow to init from a one-line "data" string
                # example: "___;___;r_r"
                x = x.split(';')

            # build llc: list of rows, each row a list of characters
            llc = [[ch for ch in row.strip()] for row in x]
            llc.reverse()

            info.width = len(llc[0])
            info.height = len(llc)
            validate_llc(llc)

            # Use llc data to figure out the level, and build self.blocks
            # and info.spaces.  self.blocks is a dict mapping a coordinate
            # tuple to a block color; info.spaces is just a set of
            # coordinate tuples.
            self.blocks = {}
            for y in range(info.height):
                for x in range(info.width):
                    loc = (x, y)
                    c = llc[y][x]
                    if c == '_':
                        # it's a space
                        info.spaces.add(loc)
                    elif c in level_blocks:
                        # it's a block (and the block is in a space)
                        self.blocks[loc] = c
                        info.spaces.add(loc)
                    else:
                        # must be a solid square
                        assert(c == '#')

            # colors: map each block color onto a count of blocks.
            self.colors = Counter(self.blocks.values())

            # parent: points to the level instance that holds the state
            # previous to the state of this level instance.
            self.parent = None

            # s_move: a string used when printing out the moves of a solution
            self.s_move = 'initial state:'

            # rank: 0 == initial state, +1 for each move
            self.rank = 0

            self.validate()

            print "Solving:", info.title
            print
            sys.stdout.flush()

        if self._update():
            print "level wasn't stable!  after updating:\n%s\n" % str(self)

    def lone_color(self):
        return any(count == 1 for count in self.colors.values())

    def is_solved(self):
        return sum(self.colors.values()) == 0

    def validate(self):
        if info.height == 0:
            raise ValueError, "need at least one row of level data"
        if info.width < 2:
            raise ValueError, "level data not wide enough"
        if self.lone_color():
            raise ValueError, "cannot have just one of any block color"
        for x, y in info.spaces:
            if not 0 <= x < info.width or not 0 <= y < info.height:
                raise ValueError, "Bad space coordinate: " + str(loc)
        for x, y in self.blocks:
            if not 0 <= x < info.width or not 0 <= y < info.height:
                raise ValueError, "Bad block coordinate: " + str(loc)
        if any(count < 0 for count in self.colors.values()):
            raise ValueError, "cannot have negative color count!"

        colors = Counter(self.blocks.values())
        for k0 in [key for key in self.colors if self.colors[key] == 0]:
            del(self.colors[k0])  # remove all keys whose value is 0
        if colors != self.colors:
            raise ValueError, "self.colors invalid!\n" + str(self.colors)

    def _look(self, loc):
        """
return color at location 'loc', or '_' if empty, or '#' for a solid sqaure.
A bad loc does not raise an error; it just returns '#'.
        """
        if loc in self.blocks:
            return self.blocks[loc]
        elif loc in info.spaces:
            return '_'
        else:
            return '#'

    def _lookxy(self, x, y):
        loc = x, y
        return self._look(loc)

    def _board_mesg(self, mesg, loc):
        x, y = loc
        return "%s %c(%d,%d)" % (mesg, self._look(loc), x, y)

    def _blocked(self, x, y):
        return self._lookxy(x, y) != '_'

    def _s_row(self, y):
        return ''.join(self._lookxy(x, y) for x in xrange(info.width))
    def data(self, ch_join=';'):
        return ch_join.join(self._s_row(y)
                for y in xrange(info.height - 1, -1, -1))

    # make repr() actually print a representation
    def __repr__(self):
        return type(self).__name__ + "(%s)" % self.data()

    # make str() work
    def __str__(self):
        return self.data('\n')


    def _move_block(self, loc_new, loc_old):
        self.blocks[loc_new] = self.blocks[loc_old]
        del(self.blocks[loc_old])

    def _explode_block(self, loc):
        if loc in info.boom_blocks:
            return

        info.boom_blocks.add(loc)
        color = self.blocks[loc]
        self.colors[color] -= 1

    def _try_move(self, loc, d):
        x, y = loc
        if not d in ('<', '>'):
            raise ValueError, "d value '%c' invalid, must be '<' or '>'" % d

        if d == '<':
            x_m = (x - 1)
        else:
            x_m = (x + 1)
        y_m = y
        loc_m = (x_m, y_m)
        if self._blocked(x_m, y_m):
            return None # blocked, so can't move there

        # Not blocked.  Let's try the move!
        # Make a duplicate level...
        m = Level(self)
        # ...try the move, and see if anything falls or explodes...
        m._move_block(loc_m, loc)
        m._update()
        if m.lone_color():
            # Whoops, we have only one block of some color.  That means
            # no solution can be found by considering this board.
            return None

        # finish the update
        m.s_move = self._board_mesg("move:", loc) + ' ' + d
        m.parent = self
        return m

    def _falls(self, loc):
        x, y = loc
        # blocks fall if they can, and only explode when at rest.

        # gravity loop: block falls until it comes to rest
        if self._blocked(x, y - 1):
            return False # it is already at rest

        while not self._blocked(x, y - 1):
            # block is free to fall so fall one step
            y -= 1

        loc_m = (x, y)
        self._move_block(loc_m, loc)
        return True # block fell to new location

    def _explodes(self, loc):
        x, y = loc
        exploded = False

        color = self._look(loc)
        # look left, right, up, and down for blocks of same color
        for e_loc in [(x-1, y), (x+1, y), (x, y-1)]:
            if e_loc in self.blocks and self.blocks[e_loc] == color:
                self._explode_block(e_loc)
                exploded = True

        if exploded:
            self._explode_block(loc)

        return exploded

    def _update(self):
        c = 0
        while True:
            # TRICKY: sum() works on functions that return a bool!
            # As you might expect, True sums as 1 and False as 0.
            f = sum(self._falls(loc) for loc in self.blocks)
            e = sum(self._explodes(loc) for loc in self.blocks)
            for loc in info.boom_blocks:
                del(self.blocks[loc])
            info.boom_blocks.clear()
            c += f + e
            if (f + e) == 0:
                # no blocks fell or exploded; board is stable, update is done
                break
        return c

    def print_moves(self):
        lst = [self]
        a = self
        while a.parent:
            a = a.parent
            lst.append(a)
        lst.reverse()
        for i, a in enumerate(lst):
            if i:
                print "Move %d of %d" % (i, len(lst) - 1)
            print a.s_move
            print a
            print


    def solve(self):
        c = 0
        seen = set()
        solutions = []

        seen.add(self.data())
        q = []
        if self.is_solved():
            solutions.append(self)
        else:
            q.append(self)

        while q:
            a = q.pop(0)

            # Show dots while solver is 'thinking' to give a progress
            # indicator.  Dots are written to stderr so they will not be
            # captured if you redirect stdout to save the solution.
            c += 1
            if c % 100 == 0:
                prn_err('.')

            if a.rank > info.best_solution:
                # We cannot beat or even match the best solution.
                # No need to think any more about this possibility.
                # Just prune this whole branch of the solution tree!
                continue

            for loc in a.blocks:
                for d in ('<', '>'):
                    m = a._try_move(loc, d)
                    if not m or m.data() in seen:
                        continue

                    if m.is_solved():
                        if info.best_solution > a.rank:
                            print "\nnew best solution: %d moves" % m.rank
                            info.best_solution = a.rank
                        else:
                            print "\nfound another solution: %d moves" % m.rank
                        solutions.append(m)
                    else:
                        seen.add(m.data())
                        q.append(m)
        print
        print "Considered %d different board configurations." % c
        print

        solutions.sort(key=lambda a: a.rank)
        for n, a in enumerate(solutions):
            print "solution %d): %d moves" % (n, a.rank)
            a.print_moves()

        if not solutions:
            print "no solutions found!"


def load_vex_file(fname):
    with open(fname, "rt") as f:
        s = f.next().strip()
        if s != "Vexed level":
            raise ValueError, "%s: not a Vexed level file" % fname
        s = f.next().strip()
        if not s.startswith("title:"):
            raise ValueError, "%s: missing title" % fname
        info.title = s[6:].lstrip()  # remove "title:"
        for s in f:
            if s.strip() == "--":
                break
        return Level(f)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print "Usage vexed_solver <vexed_level_file.vex>"
        sys.exit(1)

    fname = sys.argv[1]
    level = load_vex_file(fname)
    level.solve()
```

Here is an example level file:

```
Vexed level
title: 25-48, "Dark Lord"
--
##_f####
##_#_c##
##_#_p##
#f___###
cp___###
p#_p_f__
```

On my computer, it solves "Dark Lord" in almost exactly 10 seconds, considering 14252 different board configurations.  I wrote in Python 2.x instead of Python 3, because I want to try this with PyPy and see how fast it becomes.

Next I should work on applying A* to this.  I guess I can make a metric like "better to move an orange block toward another orange block than away" and try to work that in.  But I do want all the solutions to pop out, so maybe I'm done already.  (If there are three solutions that are all the minimum number of moves, I want to see all three.)

I welcome comments on this Python program.  I had fun writing it!

EDIT: I did try this with PyPy but I never updated this until now.  On the computer I used with PyPy, the solver could solve the "Dark Lord" level in 10 seconds using CPython; that dropped to 4 seconds with PyPy.  The cool part is that I could *see* the speedup as the JIT kicked in: this program prints dots as it is working, and under PyPy I can see the dots start out slower and then just *accelerate*.  PyPy is nifty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Studying [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) may be better than studying the actual source code. A* is written out pretty clearly there. But that feels like cheating, doesn't it?

As all good ideas, A* is actually pretty obvious in retrospective. It's fun trying to work it through, and there are a few nice insights along the way. Here's how you get to it:

Write the brute-force solver. You'll need much of what you write in the more advanced versions: a game state, and a description of getting from one state to another. You'll also end up removing duplicate states. You should have a queue of some sort for states to be considered, a set of states you've already done, and structure to hold the best solution(s) found so far. And a method that takes a state from the queue and generates a state's „neighbor“ states (ones reachable from it). That's the basic structure of classical AI algorithms. Note that you're technically „generating“ or „exploring“ a huge graph here.

After that, add a simple pruning algorithm: if a state has only one block of some color left, there's no need to consider it further. See if you can come up with other pruning algorithms (i.e. ones that mark a state as „unsolvable“). A good pruning algorithm will eliminate lots of pointless states, thus justifying the time it takes to run the pruning itself.

Then, introduce a heuristic score: rank each state with a number that tells you how „good“ the state looks – about how much more solving will it take. Make your queue a [priority queue](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html). This will allow you to consider the „best looking“ states first, so the program should come up with *a* solution faster. But, the first solution found may not actually be the best, so to be sure that you find the best one, you still need to run the whole program.

Store the minimum cost (number of moves) that you took to get to each state. Remember to update it if you find a better path. Take the states with the lowest sum of their cost and their heuristic score first; those will more likely lead to a better solution.

And here comes A*. You need to modify your heuristic function so that it *doesn't overestimate* the distance to the goal, i.e. it can be lower than the number of moves you will actually need, but not higher. Then, note that if you found a solution, its heuristic score will be 0. And, any state where the sum of its cost and heuristic is more than the cost of a solution can't lead to a better solution. So, you can prune that state. But since you're taking the states in order, once you hit that threshold you can just stop and return, since all other states in the queue would be pruned as well.

All that's left now is perfecting your heuristic: it can never overestimate, but the better estimate it gives the less time A* will take. The better the heuristic, the better your results. Take care that the heuristic doesn't take so much time to complete – you wouldn't want, say, generating the solution by brute force, even though it would give the perfect answer :)

Wikipedia has some more discussion and possible improvements, if you get this far. But the best improvements you can make at this point will likely come from improving the heuristic function.

Comment: Studying Wikipedia doesn't feel like cheating to me; if I learn the algorithm, I learn it.  Either way I'll write code.  But the rest of your comments are absolutely useful; thank you very much indeed.  Hmmm, if I was going to write the brute-force solver, I was planning to write it in C, but now I think I'll write it in Python so I have the platform upon which to try the A*.

Comment: Your comments were very helpful.  I wish I could upvote you multiple times, but at least I could accept your answer, and I did.  Please take a look at my working code; I would very much like to get feedback on it from you.  (Post it as another answer so I can upvote that one too.  I don't think that's outside the bounds of etiquette for Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Sorry, but I think [this is not the site for that](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You can try posting on codereview.stackexchange.com. Or, better yet, put this on github.com – they have some great code review infrastructure, and I'd be happy to comment on your code over there. As for the karma points, don't sweat it, they're not all that important... You're welcome to go learn from some of my [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/99057/petr-viktorin#answers) (I'd appreciate corrections more than +1s, if you have some)

Comment: Maybe I will post it over there, but your comments were so helpful in writing it that I was hoping for more advice from you on this.  I still haven't figured out how to apply A* or even if I should.  But of course I cannot compel you to help me more, and I don't want to be pushy about it.  Thank you for your very helpful advice; it is much faster because of ideas you gave me.

Comment: I'm not turning you down, just giving you better places for getting feedback on code. I'm already following you on Github :) ... Anyway, to answer the follow-up question that isn't code review: If you want *all* best solutions to pop out, terminate A* after you go *over* the threshold, not when you reach it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe translate it into a classical planning problem (using PDDL syntax). Then you can try out some planners that are freely available.

E.g. try [Fast Forward](http://www.loria.fr/~hoffmanj/ff.html).